# Tool for drawing automaton

Tags: ocaml, visualization, graphviz, dot, automaton

I am doing composition of two automaton (Actually it is a transducer). So at the of it, I want to visually represent it to analyze it.

Which is the best tool/library for the same?

People have suggested me dot and graphviz. Which is better? I am writing code in OCaml. Does that have any library to draw that?

This is an example transducer which I want to draw?

[image]

Comment: This answer contains some LaTeX code for drawing an automaton: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310253/what-fsm-captures-only-binary-strings-that-have-the-same-number-of-01-and-10/27712372#27712372

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> People have suggested me dot and graphviz. Which is better?

There is no *better* - [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) uses graphs in the [dot language](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language) as input (and output among others), and has a layout command called `dot` which lays out directed graphs.

> I am writing code in OCaml. Does that have any library to draw that?

I don't know OCaml, but it looks like there is [ocamlgraph](http://ocamlgraph.lri.fr/) which is able to create the dot graphs - see also this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8999557/63733).
It also looks like there are [graphviz ocaml extensions](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_linux_rhel.php) available for some platforms.

> This is an example transducer which I want to draw?

Not sure what the question is, but this graph looks like it has been made with graphviz.

Answer (score 2):

If you want high-quality renderings I suggest to generate [dot files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language) and then try [dot2tex](http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/) (never used it though) to generate PGF/TikZ to use with [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/). Here a [few examples](http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/gallery/) of TikZ automata renderings.