# What finite-state machine captures binary strings with equal numbers of '01' and '10'?

Tags: binary, state-machine

I need help designing a finite state machine that accepts binary strings containing as many occurrences of the pattern `01` as occurrences of the pattern `10`.

I kinda have a hard time understanding exactly which strings should be accepted and which should be rejected.

Any guidance would be welcome.

Answer (score 8):

### What is the language in question?

> [...] binary strings containing as many occurrences of the pattern `01` as occurrences of the pattern `10`. I kinda have a hard time understanding exactly which strings should be accepted and which should be rejected.

The language defined by your specs is in fact none other than the set composed of

- the empty string,
- all strings that start and end with the same character.

The empty string is accepted because it contains zero occurrences of either pattern; easy.
To understand why all non-empty accepted strings must start and end with the same character, instead of coming up with a formal proof, let's take a look at a couple of examples. I'll use

- `--` to highlight occurrences of the `01` pattern, and
- `**` to highlight occurrences of the `10` pattern.

#### String `10001010`

This string contains

- 2 occurrences of `01`, and
- 3 occurrences of `10`,

as shown below:

```
10001010
**  ****
   ----
```

Therefore, it is not accepted. Note that it doesn't start and end with the same character.

#### String `11001111`

This string contains

- 1 occurrence of `01`, and
- 1 occurrence of `10`,

as shown below:

```
11001111
 **--
```

Therefore, it is accepted. Note that it starts and ends with the same character (`1`).

You get the idea...

### A finite-state machine that describes the language in question

> I need help designing a finite state machine [...]

Here is an FSM that describes the language in question:

[image]

To convince yourself that it does indeed describe the language of interest here, you can think of

- s0 as the state that accepts only the empty string;
- s1 as the state that accepts only strings that start and end with a `0`;
- s2 as the state in which the next character needs to be a `0` for the input string so far to get accepted;
- s3 as the state that accepts only strings that start and end with a `1`;
- s4 as the state in which the next character needs to be a `1` for the input string so far to get accepted.

### Bonus!

Here the LaTeX code I wrote for drawing the FSM above.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  automata,
  positioning,
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=2cm,
    on grid,
    auto,
    scale=.8,
    transform shape,
  ]
    \node[state, initial, accepting] (s0)                     {$s_0$};
    \node[state,          accepting] (s1) [above right=of s0] {$s_1$};
    \node[state                    ] (s2) [right      =of s1] {$s_2$};
    \node[state,          accepting] (s3) [below right=of s0] {$s_3$};
    \node[state                    ] (s4) [right      =of s3] {$s_4$};

    \path[->] (s0) edge              node        {0}    (s1)
              (s1) edge [bend left]  node        {1}    (s2)
                   edge [loop above] node        {0}    ()
              (s2) edge [loop right] node        {1}    ()
                   edge [bend left]  node        {0}    (s1);
    \path[->] (s0) edge              node [swap] {1}    (s3)
              (s3) edge [bend right] node [swap] {0}    (s4)
                   edge [loop below] node        {1}    ()
              (s4) edge [loop right] node        {0}    ()
                   edge [bend right] node [swap] {1}    (s3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to be more precise in your question with the language that describes your language, because this to me sounds a lot like the classic trick question to create a FSM that recognizes L={0^n1^n: n is a positive integer} or, in plain speak, some pattern followed by the same number of a different pattern.

This cannot be done with a Deterministic or nondeterministic finite state machine because to count N you would need an infinite (or non finite) state machine.

A Grammar can solve this issue.
It would be as follows:
S-> 01S10
S-> (epsilon)   (goes away, in other words)

Comment: *this to me sounds a lot like the classic trick question to create a FSM that recognizes L={0^n1^n: n is a positive integer} [...]*. But it's not. As shown in my answer, the OP's language is regular.

Comment: I agree that your machine does accept the language as it is written. The original description suspiciously looks like a nonregular language reworded in a way that makes it regular... But maybe not.

Comment: Note that your grammar would be too restrictive. For instance, it cannot produce such strings as `101`, `1111`, etc.