# How do ɛ-transitions work in nondeterministic finite automata?

Tags: automata, nfa

I am confused about the implementation of a language by an automaton. Does the automaton go directly to the next state if there is a ɛ-transition? Suppose I have an automaton consisting of three states `a`, `b`, and `c` (where `a` is initial state and `c` the accepting state) with alphabet {0,1}. How does the following work?

```
 a----ɛ--->(b----0---->a)
             (b----1---->c)
```

Is the string "1" accepted? What if we had

```
   a---1--->b----ɛ--->c
```

? Would the string "1" be accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the automaton go directly to the next state if there is an ɛ-transition?

Roughly speaking, yes. An ɛ-transition (in a [non-deterministic finite automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton), or NFA, for short) is a transition that is not associated with the consumption of any symbol (`0` or `1`, in this case). Once you understand that, it's easy (in this case) to derive [deterministic finite automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) (or DFA, for short) that are equivalent to your NFAs and identify the languages that the latter describe.

> Suppose I have an automaton [...] Is the string "1" accepted?

Yes. Here is a nicer diagram (curtesy of LaTeX and `tikz`) of your first NFA:

[image]

An equivalent DFA would be:

[image]

Once you have that, it's easy to see that the language accepted by that NFA is the set of strings that

- start with zero or more `0`'s,
- end with exactly one `1`.

The string "1", because it starts with zero `0` and ends with one `1`, is indeed accepted.

> What if we had [...]? Would the string "1" be accepted?

Yes. Here is a nicer diagram of your second NFA:

[image]

An equivalent DFA would be:

[image]

In fact, it's easy to see that "1" is the only accepted string, here.

Comment: @mrahmat You're welcome. And thanks. If you're interested in producing nice diagrams of automata, have a look at this [other answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310253/what-finite-state-machine-captures-binary-strings-with-equal-numbers-of-01-and/27712372#27712372), where I posted some relevant LaTeX code.