# Any good tutorial for Ocamlgraph?

Tags: ocaml

I am not familiar with OCamlgraph library? I am not able to find any good documentation for the same? I am not able to run any small examples also. I want to find all cycles in graph for that I am using it.

Anyone aware of any documentation? Or a set of examples for the same?

Comment: Is it really that you can't understand the library, or is it that you simply don't understand the heavy use of modules, etc.., in the library?  (At which point, maybe the better thing is to look for references relating to the module system...)

Answer (score 3):

There is the paper on ocamlgraph:
http://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/ftp/publis/ocamlgraph.ps

And aside from the examples on the ocamlgraph homepage, there is a more compact code example here:
[How to visualize/draw automata in ocaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999557/how-to-visualize-draw-automata-in-ocaml/9011334#9011334)